# Lambda returning different values

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

I'm struggling with the following code:

- I want a method to check if a string has content or not.

> ```
> has_content  = -> (a) { a!=nil && a.strip != ''}
>
> c = ' '
>
> has_content.call(c)
> => false
> c.has_content
> => true
> ```

Why is the response different? Clearly I am lacking some Proc/lambdas knowledge.

Comment: `c.has_content` should throw error... How you get `true` ?

Comment: Btw. more idiomatic way to check empty content would be `!(a.nil? || a.empty?)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is something missing in that code that is causing such behavior.

`has_content` is not defined for String, so unless you defined it before, it should raise an error

```
1.9.3p429 :002 > ''.has_content
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_content' for "":String
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/weppos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

As a side note, here's an alternative version of your code

```
has_content = ->(a) { !a.to_s.strip.empty? }
```

And here's an example

```
has_content.(nil)
# => false
has_content.('')
# => false
has_content.(' ')
# => false
has_content.('hello')
# => true
```